# Mensaje antes de instalar APK

Tags: android

**Cordial saludo.**

Tengo una duda, al instalar un APK de una aplicación, me esta generando el siguiente mensaje:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy probando en un dispositivo Alcatel con Android 8.1.0.

Porque este mensaje?

Answer (score 0):

Es una alerta que te da el sistema para que sepas que la aplicación en cuestión envía notificaciones, por si las encuentras molestas puedes marcar el checkbox para bloquear las notificaciones de la aplicación

Comment: Notificaciones de que tipo? La app solo envia un SMS y  ya.

Comment: Notificaciones de cualquier tipo, muchos móviles Mediatek también traen esa opción que se desactiva (en Mediatek) en: Ajustes > Seguridad > App Permissions